# Bluetooth error when upgrading to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

During the upgrade to 16.04, the screen just got stuck and after a while it restarted and it got stuck on the black screen....I forcefully restarted it and now it shows me this...

```
[.  24.964300] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[.  27.009957] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0×1003 tx timeout
```

I am a new Ubuntu user please help me...

Comment: *BCM* suggests a Broadcom WiFi+Bluetooth chipset and most likely proprietary drivers. It's always recommended to disable those prior to do a release upgrade.

Comment: But now what do i do ?

Comment: The issue is not related to bluetooth, it just hangs there. The problem most likely is with video drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Try CTRL+ALT+F1, login and run `sudo apt-get install -f` but better to run a live session, take care of the backups if needed and install 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: It gives a relocation error

Comment: My problem still stays. Is there anybody can help me ?